# Js puppteer page goto does not go to next link

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

If puppeteer browser page object is accessed with browser.pages()[0], going to multiple urls consecutively fail with goto method.
Where if puppeteer browser page object is accessed with browser.newPage() which will now create a second but active page, going to multiple urls consecutively works.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
        headless: false 
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    const urls = ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.yahoo.com/']
    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        const url = urls[i];
        await page.goto(`${url}`)
    }
    await browser.close()
})()
```

Above works

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
        headless: false 
    })

    const page = await browser.pages()[0]
    const urls = ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.yahoo.com/']
    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        const url = urls[i];
        await page.goto(`${url}`)
    }
    await browser.close()
})()
```

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'goto')

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: browser.pages()[0] is not defined, probably no pages are open

Comment: But browser.pages() returns an array of pages and the page at index 0 happens to be the default page opened by the browser

Comment: are you sure? ure not doing newPage(), so there is no page open, starting page is not a page in the meaning of puppeteer

Comment: @FlashThunder, Yaroslavm answer and explanation solve the issue. I greatly appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this error, because you are trying to get page with index 0 from `Promise<Page[]>` in pending status.

To solve this issue, you should get page by index, when Promise is resolved, like

`const page = (await browser.pages())[0];`

or

`const [page] = await browser.pages();`

or

`const page = await browser.pages().then(p => p[0]);`